# Sed: Complicated replace after pattern (on same line)

Tags: sed, awk

Suppose you have some text like this:

```
  foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
  foobaz 00                  | 0a 00 0b 00 00
  foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
  bar    00                  | ab ba 00 cd 00
```

and you want to change all non-`00` on the right hand side of the `|` to be wrapped with `()`, but only if on the LHS of the `|` has `00`. The desired result:

```
  foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
  foobaz 00                  | (0a) 00 (0b) 00 00
  foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
  bar    00                  | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 00
```

Is there a good way of going about this using sed, or am I trying to stretch beyond the capabilities of the language?

Here's my work so far:

`s/[^0]\{2\}/(&)/g` wraps your RHS values

`/[^|]*00[^|]*|/` can be used  as an address to a command to operate only on valid lines

The trick now is to formulate a command that executes in a portion of the pattern space.

This really isn't line oriented, which may explain why I'm having trouble getting an expression that works.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself using sed and uttering phrases that include the word "space" (e.g. pattern space, hold space) you are using the wrong tool. sed is an excellent tool for simple subsitutions on a single line, but for anything involving more than the constructs s, g, and p (with -n) you should use awk. All that other stuff you can do with sed became obsolete in the mind-1970s when awk was invented and should have been removed then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } $1~/ 00 /{gsub(/[^ ][^0 ]|[^0 ][^ ]/,"(&)",$2)} 1' file
  foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
  foobaz 00                  | (0a) 00 (0b) 00 00
  foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
  bar    00                  | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 00
```

In case the string you want to search for ever gets more complicated than 2 0s, here's a more generally extensible approach since it doesn't require you to write an RE that negates the string:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
    $1 ~ / 00 /{
        split($2,a,/ /)
        $2=""
        for (i=2;i in a;i++)
            $2 = $2 " " (a[i] == "00" ? a[i] : "(" a[i] ")")
    }
    1
' file
  foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
  foobaz 00                  | (0a) 00 (0b) 00 00
  foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
  bar    00                  | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 00
```

Comment: Awesome. I had a feeling this was more of an awk'ish problem :). Strange how there isn't a nice way of saying "not 00. Otherwise, a very clean solution.

Comment: Yes, sadly there's no operator to negate a string. I update my answer to show a different solution that avoids that issue.

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r '/^\s*\S+\s*00/!b;s/\b([^0][^0]|0[^0]|[^0]0)\b/(&)/g' file
```

This disregards lines which do not begin with a word followed by 00. It then inserts parens round 2 character strings which are neither 0's or contain a 0 and a non-0.

Answer (score 2):

well it seems, (though I do it all the time) that piping sed to sed to sed means I didn't do it right the first time: Here's one

```
sed -r '/00.*\|/  {   ## match lines with a zero before the pipe

    ### surround tailing digits with ()
    ##  
     s/(\w\w) (\w\w) (\w\w) (\w\w) (\w\w)$/(\1) (\2) (\3) (\4) (\5)/;  

    ### replace the zeroes (00) with 00
    ##
    s/\(00\)/00/g; 

}'  txt
```

```
  foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
  foobaz 00                  | (0a) 00 (0b) 00 00
  foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
  bar    00                  | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 00
```

ok!

Comment: +1: Neat — map all the pairs of digits to `(xx)` and then replace all the `(00)` with `00`. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Ok try this!

```
$ sed '/00 *|/ { h; s/|.*/|/; x; s/.*|//; s/\(0[1-9a-f]\|[1-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)/(\1)/g; H; x; s/\n//; }' yourfile.txt
```

the output I get is this:

```
foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
foobaz 00                  | (0a) 00 (0b) 00 00
foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
bar    00                  | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 00
```

Edited, so it don't touch the line without `00` before the `|`.

Comment: The `ff` on the first line should not be touched...and you shouldn't need 3 invocations of `sed` to do the job.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ok, removed the 3 invocations of sed, now it uses the  hold buffer instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think `awk` is probably the better tool for this job, but it can be done with `sed`:

```
sed '/^[^ ]*  *00 *|/{
         :a
         s/\(|.*[^(]\)\([0-9a-f][1-9a-f]\)/\1(\2)/
         t a
         :b
         s/\(|.*[^(]\)\([1-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)/\1(\2)/
         t b
     }' data
```

The script looks for lines containing `00` before the pipe, and only applies the operations to those lines.  There are two substitute operations, each wrapped in a loop.  The `:a` and `:b` lines are labels.  The `t a` and `t b` commands are a conditional jump to the named label if there was a substitution performed since the last jump.  The two substitutions are almost symmetric; the first deals with any number not ending in 0; the second deals with any number not starting with 0; between them, they ignore `00`.  The patterns look for a pipe, any sequence of characters not ending with an open parenthesis `(`, and the appropriate pair of digits; it replaces that so that the number ends up inside parentheses.  The loops are necessary because a `g` modifier doesn't start from the beginning again, and the patterns work backwards through the numbers.

Given this data file (a slightly extended version of yours):

```
foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
foobaz 00                  | 0a 00 0b 00 00
foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
bar    00                  | ab ba 00 cd 00
fizbie    00               | ab ba 00 cd 90
fizzbuzz    00             | ab ba 00 cd 09
```

the output from the script is:

```
foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
foobaz 00                  | (0a) 00 (0b) 00 00
foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
bar    00                  | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 00
fizbie    00               | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) (90)
fizzbuzz    00             | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) (09)
```

It is moderately educational to add a `p` after each of the substitute commands, so you can see how the substitutions work:

```
foobar 42                  | ff 00 00 00 00
foobaz 00                  | 0a 00 (0b) 00 00
foobaz 00                  | (0a) 00 (0b) 00 00
foobaz 00                  | (0a) 00 (0b) 00 00
foobie 00                  | 00 00 00 00 00
bar    00                  | ab ba 00 (cd) 00
bar    00                  | ab (ba) 00 (cd) 00
bar    00                  | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 00
bar    00                  | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 00
fizbie    00               | ab ba 00 (cd) 90
fizbie    00               | ab (ba) 00 (cd) 90
fizbie    00               | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) 90
fizbie    00               | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) (90)
fizbie    00               | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) (90)
fizzbuzz    00             | ab ba 00 cd (09)
fizzbuzz    00             | ab ba 00 (cd) (09)
fizzbuzz    00             | ab (ba) 00 (cd) (09)
fizzbuzz    00             | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) (09)
fizzbuzz    00             | (ab) (ba) 00 (cd) (09)
```

Comment: Aha, that looping construct was the missing piece of the puzzle! Good information to remember. I can rest easy knowing that sed can indeed accomplish the task, albeit a bit round-a-bout.

Comment: Yes, the `awk` solution is neater, though.  I suspect there are other ways to do the `awk` solution, but they're all neater than `sed`.  The looping construct is powerful, though.  In fact, I read somewhere (from a link on SO) that [`sed` is Turing complete](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/proof-that-sed-is-turing-complete/) — but it is not a good choice for a general purpose language.

Comment: though two leading spaces from the input are removed ;)

Comment: @Dru: I assumed that the data probably doesn't have leading spaces; the example data also only had a single word before the `00`.  The only necessary change is in the pattern that detects the `00` before the pipe; it can be changed to `/00.*|/' or anything else that is relevant.